# Rails : How to save extra field on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, has-many

I actually have a has_many through association in order to link parents and childrens from a users table.
So here is what I've got in my models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parents_to_children, class_name: ParentsUser, foreign_key: :children_id
  has_many :parents, through: :parents_to_children, source: :parent

  has_many :children_to_parents, class_name: ParentsUser, foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :childrens, through: :children_to_parents, source: :children
end

class ParentsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: User
  belongs_to :children, class_name: User
end
```

My join table looks like as follow :

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
| id |  children_id  |  parent_id  |  relation_type  |
|----------------------------------------------------|
```

In order to save the data, I'm doing it (so far) :

```
resource.childrens << user if user
```

This works fine and well, but unfortunately, the relation_type is not saved (params[:user][:relation]).

So I've tried to do :

```
resource.childrens.build(childrens: [user], relation_type: params[:user][:relation]) if user
```

But I'm getting an error : `unknown attribute: relation_type`

Any ideas on how to achieve this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Write this in your `User` Model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents_user
```

This could resolve the Issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I realized that I needed to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. However, I still have an issue as I dont know at all how to append those data onto my `resource.childrens`. Ideas?

Comment: How about using strong parameters?

Comment: well Im already allowing `[:relation]` params to pass : `u.permit(:relation)`

Comment: Can you post your user schema?